# Sub-query - Return records that occurred after record from Main query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to return a count of readings and the actual reading (BP_SYS_LAST, BP_DIA_Last) that occurred up to 6months after HTN_Watchlist.BP_SYS_LAST_DT

The where clause in my subquery was 
Where BP_SYS_LAST_DT > HTN_Watchlist.BP_SYS_LAST_DT and 
BP_SYS_LAST_DT <= DATEADD(m, 6, HTN_Watchlist.BP_SYS_LAST_DT)

Any suggestions on how to do this?
Thanks

```
Select 
  HTN_Watchlist.LOC_NAME, 
  HTN_Watchlist.PAT_MRN_ID, 
  HTN_Watchlist.PAT_NAME, 
  HTN_Watchlist.BP_SYS_LAST, 
  HTN_Watchlist.BP_DIA_LAST, 
  HTN_Watchlist.BP_SYS_LAST_DT,
  HTN_Watchlist.BP_DIA_LAST_DT


From

   (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CLARITY_LOC.LOC_NAME, 
    PATIENT.PAT_MRN_ID, 
    PATIENT.PAT_NAME, 
    DM_HYPERTEN_HX.BP_SYS_LAST, 
    DM_HYPERTEN_HX.BP_DIA_LAST, 
    DM_HYPERTEN_HX.BP_SYS_LAST_DT,
    DM_HYPERTEN_HX.BP_DIA_LAST_DT 
    FROM   CLARITY.dbo.PATIENT PATIENT 
        INNER JOIN CLARITY.dbo.DM_HYPERTEN_HX DM_HYPERTEN_HX ON PATIENT.PAT_ID=DM_HYPERTEN_HX.PAT_ID
        INNER JOIN CLARITY.dbo.CLARITY_LOC CLARITY_LOC ON DM_HYPERTEN_HX.CUR_PRIM_LOC_ID=CLARITY_LOC.LOC_ID
    WHERE   (
        DM_HYPERTEN_HX.BP_SYS_LAST > 140 
     or DM_HYPERTEN_HX.BP_DIA_LAST > 90
     ) 
    ) As HTN_Watchlist
```

Comment: What results are you getting, and how are they different from the results you are trying to get?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you are trying to do.